# How do you call a model using interactive (not combined) predictors?

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, regression

How do you call a model using interactive (not combined) predictors?

I've got a regression model that works great:

```
lm_comb1 <- lm(cbind(MD_EARN_WNE_P10, X40.year.NPV) ~ SAT_AVG*TUITIONFEE_OUT*AVGFACSAL* RET_FT4_POOLED*INEXPFTE*C100_4_POOLED,data = training_set_NORM)
```

When I call for `summary(lm_comb1)` I encounter no problem. I wish to check how adding a polynomial will affect things, so I fit:

```
lm_comb1_POLY2 <- lm(formula = cbind(training_set_NORM$MD_EARN_WNE_P10, training_set_NORM$X40.year.NPV) ~ poly(training_set_NORM$SAT_AVG,2,raw=TRUE)*poly(training_set_NORM$TUITIONFEE_OUT,2,raw=TRUE)*poly(training_set_NORM$AVGFACSAL,2,raw=TRUE)*poly(training_set_NORM$RET_FT4_POOLED,2,raw=TRUE)*poly(training_set_NORM$INEXPFTE,2,raw=TRUE)*poly(training_set_NORM$C100_4_POOLED,2,raw=TRUE))
```

When I add `summary(lm_comb1_POLY2)`, however, R-markdown will not knit an output. It goes all the way to 100% but never produces an actual output. I've tried knitting to HTML as well as PDF. I do not receive an error message, but when I remove `summary(lm_comb1_POLY2)` the output is knit and produced just fine.

Any ideas? Is there something flakey about how I've called `m_comb1_POLY2`? Do the `*` rather than `+` operators screw things up somehow?

Note: I've provided no data as the question does not seem to call for reproducibility.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It dawned on me to try

```
lm_comb1_POLY2 <- lm(cbind(MD_EARN_WNE_P10, X40.year.NPV) ~ poly(SAT_AVG*TUITIONFEE_OUT*AVGFACSAL* RET_FT4_POOLED*INEXPFTE*C100_4_POOLED,2,raw=TRUE), data = training_set_NORM)
summary(lm_comb1_POLY2.1)
```

and this appears to work. If any experts come along, please do correct me, though. Hope this helps someone else!